# How to parse delimited fields with some (sub)fields empty?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I use Spark 2.1.1 and Scala 2.11.8 in spark-shell.

My input dataset is something like :

```
2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , z287570731_serv80i:7:175 , 5:Re

2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , p286274731_serv80i:6:100 , 138 

2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , t219420679_serv37i:2:50 , 5

2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , v290380588_serv81i:12:800 , 144:Jo

2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , z292902510_serv83i:4:45 , 5:Re

2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , v205454093_serv75i:5:70 , 50:AK
```

It is saved as a CSV file which is read using `sc.textFile("input path")`

After a few transformations, this is the output of the RDD I have:

```
(String, String) = ("Re ",7)
```

I get this by executing

```
val tid = read_file.map { line =>
  val arr = line.split(",")
  (arr(3).split(":")(1), arr(2).split(":")(1))
}
```

My input RDD is:

```
( z287570731_serv80i:7:175 , 5:Re )

( p286274731_serv80i:6:100 , 138 )

( t219420679_serv37i:2:50 , 5 )

( v290380588_serv81i:12:800 , 144:Jo )

( z292902510_serv83i:4:45 , 5:Re )
```

As it can be observed, in the first entry column 2, I have

```
5:Re
```

of which I'm getting the output

```
("Re ",7)
```

However when I reach the second row, according to the format, column 2 is 138 which should be

```
138:null
```

but gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on executing

```
tid.collect()
```

How can I correct this so that null is displayed with 138 and 5 for the second and third rows respectively? I tried to do it this way:

```
tid.filter(x => x._1 != null )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is as below in a file

```
( z287570731_serv80i:7:175 , 5:Re )
( p286274731_serv80i:6:100 , 138 )
( t219420679_serv37i:2:50 , 5 )
( v290380588_serv81i:12:800 , 144:Jo )
( z292902510_serv83i:4:45 , 5:Re )
```

Then you can use

```
val tid = sc.textFile("path to the input file")
  .map(line => line.split(","))
  .map(array => {
    if (array(1).contains(":")) (array(1).split(":")(1).replace(")", "").trim, array(0).split(":")(1))
    else (null, array(0).split(":")(1))
  })
tid.foreach(println)
```

which should give you output as

```
(Re,7)
(null,6)
(null,2)
(Jo,12)
(Re,4)
```

But if you have data as

```
2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , z287570731_serv80i:7:175 , 5:Re
2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , p286274731_serv80i:6:100 , 138
2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , t219420679_serv37i:2:50 , 5
2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , v290380588_serv81i:12:800 , 144:Jo
2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , z292902510_serv83i:4:45 , 5:Re
2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , v205454093_serv75i:5:70 , 50:AK
2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , z287096299_serv80i:19:15000 , 39:Re
```

Then you need to do

```
val tid = sc.textFile("path to the input file")
  .map(line => line.split(","))
  .map(array => {
    if (array(3).contains(":")) (array(3).split(":")(1).replace(")", "").trim, array(2).split(":")(1))
    else (null, array(2).split(":")(1))
  })
tid.foreach(println)
```

And you should have output as

```
(Re,7)
(null,6)
(null,2)
(Jo,12)
(Re,4)
(AK,5)
(Re,19)
```

Comment: (null,00)
(null,00)
(null,00)
(null,00) is the output I'm getting

Comment: Is your input the same as defined?

Comment: share your input file sample data. May be I can help . :)

Comment: does it mean that your input file is a single line?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you expect at least two parts in the position while you may have only one.

The following is the line that causes the issue.

```
{var arr = line.split(","); (arr(3).split(":")(1),arr(2).split(":")(1))});
```

After you do `line.split(",")` you then `arr(3).split(":")(1)` and also `arr(2).split(":")(1)`.

There's certainly too much assumption about the format and got beaten by missing values.

> but gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on executing

That's because you access `3` and `2` elements but have only 2 (!)

```
scala> sc.textFile("input.csv").
  map { line => line.split(",").toSeq }.
  foreach(println)
WrappedArray(( z287570731_serv80i:7:175i ,  5:Re ))
WrappedArray(( p286274731_serv80i:6:100 ,  138 ))
```

The problem has almost nothing to do with Spark. It's a regular Scala problem where the data is not where you expect it.

```
scala> val arr = "hello,world".split(",")
arr: Array[String] = Array(hello, world)
```

Note that what's above is just a pure Scala.

### Solution 1 - Spark Core's RDDs

Given the following dataset...

```
2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , z287570731_serv80i:7:175 , 5:Re
2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , p286274731_serv80i:6:100 , 138 
2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , t219420679_serv37i:2:50 , 5
2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , v290380588_serv81i:12:800 , 144:Jo
2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , z292902510_serv83i:4:45 , 5:Re
2017-06-18 00:00:00 , 1497769200 , v205454093_serv75i:5:70 , 50:AK
```

...I'd do the following:

```
val solution = sc.textFile("input.csv").
  map { line => line.split(",") }.
  map { case Array(_, _, third, fourth) => (third, fourth) }.
  map { case (third, fourth) =>
    val Array(_, a @ _*) = fourth.split(":")
    val Array(_, right, _) = third.split(":")
    (a.headOption.orNull, right)
  }
scala> solution.foreach(println)
(Re,7)
(null,6)
(Re,4)
(null,2)
(AK,5)
(Jo,12)
```

### Solution 2 - Spark SQL's DataFrames

I **strongly** recommend using Spark SQL for such data transformations. As you said, you are new to Spark, so why not start from the right place which is exactly Spark SQL.

```
val solution = spark.
  read.
  csv("input.csv").
  select($"_c2" as "third", $"_c3" as "fourth").
  withColumn("a", split($"fourth", ":")).
  withColumn("left", $"a"(1)).
  withColumn("right", split($"third", ":")(1)).
  select("left", "right")
scala> solution.show(false)
+----+-----+
|left|right|
+----+-----+
|Re  |7    |
|null|6    |
|null|2    |
|Jo  |12   |
|Re  |4    |
|AK  |5    |
+----+-----+
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice, thanks a lot. But I'll explain the entire problem here. I have to map the values in the two columns say (Re, 5) ; (Null, 6) ; (Null, 5) ; (Jo, 12) and (Re, 4). The places like 138 and 5 which have no data like the first row (5:Re) have to be marked null and then the number of occurrences of Re, Jo, Null etc have to be counted. I don't understand how 'if' helps here.

Comment: All the code has to be executed in a single line, right? Also I think my approach towards learning Spark and Scala has been wrong so far. Can you please suggest to me how I should start?

Comment: Could be but does not have to. I formatted it so you can copy and paste it to `spark-shell` and see how it works yourself.

Comment: I did. I got an error saying "value split is not a member of Array[String]"

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Does `val Array(_, a @ _*) = rt.split(":")` mean _"move all elements of Array `rt.split(":")` to `a` except the first one"_?

Comment: Interesting. Looks like we have the input different. Can you remove the last `map` and see what you get.

Comment: @philantrovert yes.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` is occurring because the element will not be there if no `:` is present in the second element of the tuple.
You can check if `:` is present in the second element of each tuple. And then use map to give you an intermediate RDD on which you can run your current query.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(
    ( "z287570731_serv80i:7:175" , "5:Re" ),
    ( "p286274731_serv80i:6:100" , "138" ),
    ( "t219420679_serv37i:2:50" , "5" ),
    ( "v290380588_serv81i:12:800" , "144:Jo" ),
    ( "z292902510_serv83i:4:45" , "5:Re" )))


rdd.map { x =>
    val idx = x._2.lastIndexOf(":")
    if(idx == -1) (x._1, x._2+":null")
    else (x._1, x._2)
}
```

There are obviously better (lesser lines of code) ways to do what you want to accomplish but as a beginner, it's good to layout each step in a single command so t's easily readable and understandable, specially with `scala` where you can stop global warming with a single line of code.

Comment: Why do I get "values _2 and _1 are not members of string" on executing rdd.map?

Comment: Because in this example, I used a `Tuple2` to store the fields. Since, you are using `split` on a line, you'll probable get an `Array`, so you can try using `x(0)` , `x(1)`. It depends on how your RDD looks like. `x._1` is for tuples. `x(0)` in for arrays.